# Vue method to return all properties belonging to a single user returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

Below is a dropdown which should ideally display a list of all tables belonging to a particular user.

```
<v-select
    :items="allTables"
    :item-text="tableNames"
    return-object
/>
```

This is the structure of **allTables**. There could be more or less depending on the user:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "TABLE"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "KOP"
    }
]
```

This is the method which displays tableNames:

```
tableNames() {
    this.allTables.forEach(el => {
        return element.map(a=>a.name)
    });
},
```

Originally it was like this (however it led to the error I've listed in one of the answers):

```
tableNames: item => item.name;
```

Console logging

```
console.log(el.map(a=>a.name))
```

within the method above returns an array like below ('TABLE' is the name of a table and 'KOP' is the name of another table).

[image]

It's not returning any errors but the options for the v-select return [object Object]. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can I ask why it's returning this?

[image]

The function to get all tables:

```
public function retrieveAllTables()
{
    return Auth::user()->client->tables()->get();
}
```

Data variable:

```
data: () => ({
    allTables: []
}),
```

API request:

```
getAllTables() {
    apiClientGet(
        routes["pages.retrieveAllTables"],
        null,
        response => {
            this.allTables.push(response.data.flat());
            // console logging this.allTables shows the structure above
        }
    );
},
```

Comment: tableNames doesn't return anything. You're misusing forEach there.

Comment: I read this as 'for each table (item) in the array, log the name'. Which to me makes sense (though if I am wrong which given this issue is likely the case, can I ask why it doesn't return anything?) Does it need to be written as a computed value?

Comment: What's the purpose of logging (it doesn't do logging, it's a noop) if it doesn't return a value? `tableNames() === undefined` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the api request wan't actually pushing the responses to allTables.

```
getAllTables() {
    apiClientGet(
        routes["pages.retrieveAllTables"],
        null,
        response => {
            this.allTables = response.data;
            return this.allTables;
        }
    );
},
```

I figured it out because console logging allTables in beforeMount returned an empty array when it should not have